# Get option value from select element after change

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client code suppose to get the value selected from a `select` html element after it gets changed but currently it gets the whole element every time the select element gets clicked.
How can I get the value of the element and only after it gets changed? Thanks

here what the option looks like

```
<select name="foodItem>
   <option value="0">        
   <option value="1">        
</select>



Template.food.events({
  "click select[name='foodItem']": function(event, opt) {
    console.log(opt.find(':selected'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Try `change`  event instead

Comment: @PranavCBalan thanks, and how do I get only the value of the `value` attribute?

Comment: `opt.find(':selected').value`

Comment: Separately, once you switch to using `click`, `event.target.value` will contain the value since the `target` is the `select` element and for a single-select, its `value` property will contain the value. No need for the `opt.find` at all.

Comment: @PranavCBalan: I couldn't find anything in [the Meteor docs I quickly found](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/forms-and-events#!) about there being a second argument, so I just went with `event.target`. But as I don't know Meteor, probably just found incomplete or outdated info.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I'm wrong `event.target.value` is the  right way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use change event instead

```
Template.food.events({
  "change select[name='foodItem']": function(event, opt) {
    console.log(opt.find(':selected'));
    // to get selected value use 
    // event.target.value
  }
});
```